# Janus mjr having loss of packets issue

Tags: video-processing, janus, janus-gateway

I have video recording from Janus as mjr, having loss of packets issue while processing the video, how can I overcome this.

```
janus-pp-rec $FILE-video.mjr $FILE-video.webm
```

when I use this I'm getting the below in outputs

```
[WARN] [FILL] pos: 004091, writing silences (count=2)
[WARN] Lost a packet here? (got seq 5355 after 5348, time ~82s)
[WARN] [FILL] pos: 004095, writing silences (count=6)
[WARN] Lost a packet here? (got seq 5358 after 5355, time ~82s)
```

I tried using ffmpeg -bsf option but ffmpeg tool is not able to process these mjr files.

I tried with ffmpeg -bsf option but it is not able to process the mjr